# Doubt about invertibility in Group Algebra over a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-rings

Let $C=\langle c \rangle$ denote the cyclic group of order $2$ written multiplicatively, i.e. $C$ is a copy of $\{\pm 1\}$ with the usual product, and let $k$ be a field of characteristic different from $2$. Now consider the group algebra

$$k[C]=\{\alpha +\beta c|\alpha,\beta\in k\}$$

and the augmentation morphism

$$\lambda (\alpha +\beta c)=\alpha +\beta,$$

which has $\ker\lambda =k(1-c)$. We know that this ideal is actually the Jacbson radical of $k[C]$ and so that $\mathcal{U}(k[C])=k[C]\setminus \ker\lambda$, where $\mathcal{U}$ denotes the group of unit of a ring.

Now my problem comes when I consider the element $1+c$, which is not in $\ker\lambda$ since we are assuming $k$ has characteristic different from $2$, which means that it should be invertible. However $(1-c)(1+c)=1-c^2=0$, hence $1+c$ is a zero-divisor and it cannot be invertible!

Where am I wrong with my reasoning? I know it's something really trivial but I'm lost; any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *We know that this ideal is actually the Jacbson radical of $k[C]$* what I know is that Maschke's theorem says this ring is semisimple Artinian, having Jacobson radical zero.  The augmentation ideal is quite frequently not the same as the Jacobson radical...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you calculate the regular matrix representation, $c$ is clearly represented by the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$, which gives for $c+1$ the non-invertible matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\1&1\end{array}\right)$. So indeed $1+c$ is non-invertible. The statement that every element outside the Jacobson radical is invertible is wrong - it would imply, for example that every element of a semisimple algebra is invertible, which is patently untrue.

Comment: Thanks, everything is clear now. I really have to revise my notes.

Answer (score 2):

ker $\lambda$ is not the jacobson radical. k(1+c) is also a maximal ideal. So the Jacobson radical is (0).